# MySQL not picking up symlinked cnf changes in 5.7.13 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, my.cnf, apparmor

EDIT: I may have found what might be part of the issue, further edit at the bottom.

I've got a new server setup running mysql everything seems to be okay. Except whenever I use show variables the configuration settings I can see in my .cnf file are not being shown and what appear to be general defaults are being shown. So it would appear while I can use mysql just fine, the settings are all just the defaults.

I am trying to figure out why my .cnf is not being used. I have taken a number of steps to check that it is definitely being loaded and these are laid out below. Once I am sure it is being loaded I am at a loss as to how to explain why my settings aren't being used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The location of my cnf file is this:

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

I have attempted to verify that this is what is being used by the following:

`sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>
> /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

`/etc/my.cnf` does not exist

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`

`/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` is a symlink to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`

`/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` contains:

> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

`etc/mysql/conf.d/` is a directory that contains:

> mysql.cnf
>
> mysqldump.cnf

`mysql.cnf` is empty so presumably isn’t doing anything

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` is a directory that contains:

> mysqld.cnf
>
> mysqld.cnf.dpkg-new
>
> mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

`mysqld.cnf` is a symlink to `/home/{my_username}/conf/mysqld.cnf`

`/home/{my_username}/conf/mysqld.cnf` is my conf file which I expect it to be using.

So I cannot see the problem it looks like it should be using my config.

In a second attempt to verify that this .cnf is being used I used `strace mysql`. My file was listed and opened along with the other paths I just listed above.

```
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2262, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2262, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Generated by Percona Configura"..., 4096) = 2262
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                          = 0 close(4)
```

Again it looks like it should be using the .cnf file.

Can anyone offer any insight into why it's not?

EDIT: I've just done a `strace mysqld` instead of `strace mysql` and I get a permission error on my .cnf file. This could be the problem. But I don't understand enough about the difference between mysql and mysqld can anyone explain?

```
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3218, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question.

Comment: Sorry i'm not familiar with what that means?

Comment: DBA=database administrator. They have their own site in the stackexchange world

Comment: Is it within the rules to cross post?

Comment: Not really. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu for guidance. I have already voted to migrate this question to the DBA site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused and resolved by apparmor

> Ubuntu comes with something called AppArmor, a kernel-integrated
>   application security system that controls how applications can access
>   the file system. Source: [Oracle Article](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql)

If you put the .cnf in a custom location, you need to give mysql permissions to access that directory. In my case I needed to edit this `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` with the following:

```
/home/{my_username}/conf/mysqld.cnf r
```

You could also use:

```
/home/{my_username}/conf/* r
```

To give it access to the whole directory.

Comment: How did you find this? Was it logged somewhere?